# Fast and light image cropping for webpages

Tags: php, image, crop

I have a website on a server and I want to make another server that will crop stored images 'on the fly' so the website on the other server can use them. I found a lot of info about libraries I can use to crop images, but I need to find the most light and fast solution. First I was thinking about ImageMagic for PHP but I think that using C/C++ for cropping will be better. What language/library should I use?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of achieving what you wish.

One of them is using the logic you have already come up with, the separate machine which does this. I would not use a another server for this job, especially if you are cropping/resizing on the fly, which means that your process will wait for that other server to finish anyway.
I would use the same machine for this, or another one, but over there I would have a cronjob doing these things.
As for the lib, I would recommend GD, I found it much easier to use then Imagemagick.

The other way, which is a bit more interesting from my point of view, is doing all this on the user's machine in his browser with the help of HTML5 canvas. But this would only work if that browser supports this feature.

**UPDATE**

Reading my answer it came to me that the ideal solution would be using both. Where you can, you use the client machine's resources, where you cannot, you use tha server-side cropping/resizing fallback.